# Updating Applications with Vulnerabilities

Tags: security, distro-recommendation

I am using the default Ubuntu Distros in an Azure Bionic VM. I would like to update software with vulnerabilities such as VIM, but it seems the only version available in these Distros is version 8.0. Shouldn't the security distro have an update available for VIM and any other software with vulnerabilities ? Need some 101 Guidance here please.

[sources.list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O45ch.png)

Comment: The answer to the specific question asked (*Shouldn't the security distro have an update available?*) is 'No' *because of the way you phrased the question*. There are two ways to address a vulnerability: 1) Apply a patch to the current version, or 2) Update to a newer version (that includes the patch). The question assumes the #2 is preferable. The Ubuntu Security Team actually does #1 for most CVEs (there are exceptions).

Comment: Refer to the following posts for some more useful information on this topic: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) and [my answer to another question summarizing generally 'when a security patch happens'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362875/ubuntu-release-update-packages/1362877#1362877).

Comment: Part of the 'update' process is to backport packages, and if there's a Vim update they'll issue a [USN here](https://www.bing.com/newtabredir?url=https%3A%2F%2Fubuntu.com%2Fsecurity%2Fnotices)

Comment: If you ever want to see what version and what changes they have made to a package just run `apt changelog <app name>` like `apt changelog vim` will actually show that it is version `8.1.2269-1ubuntu5` for Ubuntu 20.04 repos.